# wordpress archive list of post separated yearly

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I have an time line post page.
I want to separate this by publish year.
For example:

```
2014
post 1
post 2
post 3

2013
post 1
post 2
post 3
```

Now post loop is ok. But I want add year each first line of yearly post loop. 
I'm using the code below. How can I add the year?

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;?>
<?php $media = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'category_name' => 'media',
                        'posts_per_page' => 50,
                        'paged' => $paged
                )); 
?>


<?php if( $media->have_posts()) : while($media->have_posts()) : $media->the_post(); ?>
<span class="app_tl_time">2014</span>
<article class="app_tl_article">
    <span class="app_tl_arrow"></span>
                <div class="app_tl_title">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                 <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php if ($media->max_num_pages > 1) { ?>
    <nav class="prev-next-posts">
        <div class="prev-posts-link">
            <?php // display older posts link
                  echo get_next_posts_link( 'Prev', $media->max_num_pages );  
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="next-posts-link">
           <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); // display newer posts link ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
<?php } ?>
<?php else: ?>
<article>
    <p><?php _e('Nothing.'); ?></p>
</article>
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!--app_timeline_grid-->
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built-in function for this called [wp_get_archives()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives). In your case:

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array('type' => 'yearly') ); ?>
```

Read more about creating archives by year [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index#List_Archives_By_Year).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want show more field. (thumbnail, excerpt and more).So I need custom php help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just see the page Template_Hierarchy for just create copy archive rename to 2014.php or date.php

[image]

OR
[wp get archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you can get the result

```html
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

foreach ( $years as $year ) {
    // get posts for each year
    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );

    echo '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2><ul>';

    foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {

        echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';        
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I grouped a custom post type by year

```
$posts = get_posts(['post_type' => 'news', 'numberposts' => -1]);
$years = [];

// seperate posts by years

foreach($posts as $post){
  $year = date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date));

  if( ! isset( $years[$year] ) ){
    $years[$year] = [];
  }

  array_push($years[$year], $post);
}
```